# Copy Local Doesn't Consider Publisher Policy in the GAC

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that references an older copy of Oracle.DataAccess.dll in myproject\dependencies.  Because I have a different version installed of the rest of the oracle data access components, I set copy local = false, relying on the publisher policy in the GAC to handle the redirection to the proper version.  At run time, this works fine.  However, at compile time, the copy local=false setting is being ignored resulting in the referenced oracle.dataaccess.dll being copied to the bin directory.  Is there a reason that the compiler doesn't follow the same probing rules that the runtime does?  Is there a fix?

Comment: By the way, the reason for the reference to the older version is because that is the version on the server that I want to guarantee compatability with.  It drives me nuts when every developer has a different install path for a component and they need to change the reference, which constantly ends up getting checked in.

Comment: You are absolutely correct Hans.  Please formally post your answer so i can give you credit.